# php file not executing python script when called through browser

Tags: web-server, python-3, php, apache-httpd, permissions

I have an apache2 webserver running on the pi. I have a php file that uses exec() to run a python script. Everything works well from the command line. when loaded through the browser, the exec() function returns nothing. The python script works when executed using `sudo -u www-data`. `php file.php` also works from the terminal, but not through the browser. When i try `sudo -u www-data php file.php,` it asks for the password, which i didnt set. What should I do? Here is the output of `ls -l` command.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   125 Jul  2 19:52 test.php
-rwxr-x--- 1 www-data www-data   218 Jul  2 19:44 lights.py
```

THE PHP FILE

```
<?php
ini_set('DISPLAY_ERRORS',1);
echo(shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/control/lights.py"));
?>
```

Comment: determine if the python script gets called by PHP

Comment: Have you added the www-data user to the GPIO group? What shows up in /var/log/apache2/error.log when the script fails?